# How do I assign a PHP array to a JS array?

Tags: php, javascript

Below is my code where  the **php array $keys** assigned to a **JS array var keysArr**,
But the value display on the alert box is not correct.

Thus, there is something wrong on assign Php array to Js array.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
$keys = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var keysArr = <?php print $keys?>;
        for (var i = 0; i < keysArr.length; ++i){

                    alert(keysArr[i]);

        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
$keys = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var keysArr = Array(<?php echo implode(',',$keys);?>);
        for (var i = 0; i < keysArr.length; ++i){

                    alert(keysArr[i]);

        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

whith print you're just showing `Array`, and not proper array code for js. Look inside the HTML you generate.

Comment: That will break horribly for any array containing non-Number data or any array consisting of just one value.

Comment: yes, youre right. It will only work for arrays containg more than one number.

Answer (score 9):

```
var keysArr = <?php json_encode($keys) ?>;
```

requires PHP >= 5.2.0, but third-party json_encode() implementations are available for older versions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it doesn't need JSON extension:

```
var keysArr = [ <?php print implode(',', $keys); ?> ];
    for (var i = 0; i < keysArr.length; ++i){
        alert(keysArr[i]);
    }
```

Comment: That will break horribly for any array containing non-Number data

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$keys = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var keysArr = Array(<?php foreach($keys as $key) echo (is_numeric($key))? $key : '"'.$key.'"' ;?>);
        for (var i = 0; i < keysArr.length; ++i){

                    alert(keysArr[i]);

        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Try this... I haven't tested it yet, but it would print numbers without quotes (") and other stuff with them.